# MySQL query with "not exists" takes too long

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

u

My query is

```
SELECT *, 
       week (pdate,3) 
  FROM pubmed
 where not exists (select 1 
                     from screened 
                    where suser=86
                      and ssearch=pubmed.aid)
 order by pdate desc
```

Screened has only 30000 records, but the query takes several minutes.

Pubmed.aid is the primary index.

I think I have created all the indexes I can use. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you do an `EXPLAIN` on the query and paste the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't format it in comments, adding it here
try LEFT JOIN

```
   SELECT P.*,week (P.pdate,3) 
   FROM pubmed P
   LEFT JOIN screened S
   ON S.ssearch = P.aid 
   AND S.suser = 86
   WHERE S.ssearch is NULL
   order by P.pdate
```

Comment: I think the space in `week (` needs to be removed. Also, a compound index on `screened (suser,ssearch)` may accelerate this query a lot.